# Substituting variable names with other variable names

Tags: php

I don't know if this is possible, and if it is I don't know what it's called so I'm not sure what to search for online, but I am curious to know if it is possible (I won't actually be using this code, I would just like to know if it can be done)

Say we have 3 variables:

```
$var_1 = "A";
$var_2 = "B";
$var_3 = "C";
```

Would it be possible to do something like this(I know this particular code doesn't work, I've tried):

```
$arr = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
{
    $arr[] = $var_{$i};
}
var_dump($arr);
```

So that `{$i}` becomes part of the variable name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course!

```
$arr[] = ${"var_$i"};
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
)
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/533135)**

And oh, this concept is called ***[Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)***

Comment: I will mark this one as the accepted answer (in 5 minutes, when it lets me) as you also supplied me with the name of the concept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this in following way:

```
<?php
$var_1 = "A";
$var_2 = "B";
$var_3 = "C";

//$arr = array(); // no need to declare this as an array
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
{
 $arr[] = ${"var_".$i};

}
var_dump($arr);

?>
```